# Is it better to have Foreign Keys in Main Table, or to reference main table in secondary table

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database

If I had a main table called Products, and a secondary table called Types.

Types is basically a description table. (Clothes, Toys, Food etc)

Should I have TypesId in the Products table? or should I have ProductsId in the Types table? or both

Having ProductId in the Type table would allow Type to be able to be dropped if the Types table was not needed anymore. which would enforce a none to many

Having it the other way, would enforce a Product to always have a type. (so a one to one)

Any advice would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypesId in Products table. You need to ask yourself whether Product always need to be a type and then if the answer is yes, make it a foreign key.

You cannot make ProductsId in Types table, since you will have multiple products ( shirts, pants ) with same type ( clothes).

Comment: oh right! basically if its a one to one relationship (referencing a static table) I should keep the fk in the main table (Product) otherwise I would have to keep adding rows to the secondary table